# Add another textview under the previous textview as a second textview

Tags: java, android

guys I tried to add another textview but when I tried the new textview has been placed on the previous textview how can I make the second textview goes down as a new second text view

This is my code I hope you can help me

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/state1"
android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer1"
android:textSize="12sp" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/sayer2"
android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/state2"
android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? What is the relation with Python?

Answer (score 0):

Simple just wrap those two TextView with LinearLayout and slightly align a Bit.

this would be very neat rather than just positioning inside the relative layout. because if you wanna move entire wrap TextView will move alongside. so you don't need to worry about aligning each TextView

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" > 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/state1"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/sayer1"
    android:textSize="12sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only align one TextView based on the parent and the rest based on that one.

Or put in other words, if you are not setting a **layout_** parameter, then you should align it with the parent so the view knows where to position itself. Now, the other views can use **layout_** parameters against the view that has an **alignParent** parameter.

If you align all of them against the parent, they will just align keeping the parent in mind and not bother about the other TextViews.

I like to imagine that they view that is aligned with the parent is a sort of "anchor" and the other ones position themselves against it.

Try the following (I removed the to other parameters for **readability** not because you should remove them!)

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/secondLine"
android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />
//If You set it below, there's no reason to align it with the Parent
// you can now use margins instead

<TextView
android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
android:layout_below="@id/textView2" />
//Same scenario

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  />
//In this case you DO need to align with parent because you are not setting a 
//layout_ parameter
```

I hope this helps guide you in the right direction. Also, keep in mind that if you change the values on the views with **alignParent** parameter, the other views that have a **layout_** parameter and will also change in position.

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml file to following. It might help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/state1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/sayer1"
        android:textSize="12sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/sayer2"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/state2"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Then in `LinearLayout`, try updating `android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`... This might be the cause that the parent layout height is not sufficient enough to display all textviews